# Tuple Indexing, Combine Slice and Index

Tags: python, indexing, slice

i have got a question about tuple indexing and slicing in python. I want to write better and clearer code. This is a simplified version of my problem:
I have a tuple `a = (1,2,3,4,5)` and i want to index into it so that i get `b = (1,2,4)`.
Is it possible to do this in one operation or do i have do `b = a[0:2] + (a[3],)`? I have thought about indexing with another tuple, which is not possible, i have also searched if there is a way to combine a slice and an index. It just seems to me, that there must be a better way to do it.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: °^^^ please put into answer - deserve more credits.

Comment: Solutions belong in answers, not in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment you can use `itemgetter`

```
import operator
a = (1,2,3,4)
result = operator.itemgetter(0, 1, 3)(a)
```

If you do this kind of indexing often and your arrays are big, you might also have a look at `numpy` as it supports more complex indexing schemes:

```
import numpy as np
a = (1,2,3,4)
b = np.array(a)
result = b[[0,1,3]]
```

If the array is very large and or you have a huge list of single points you want to include it will get convinient to construct the slicing list in advance. For the example above it will look like this:

```
singlePoints = [3,]
idx = [*range(0,2), *singlePoints]
result = b[idx]
```

Comment: Thank you as well, i will use that. I normally use numpy, that is why i thought that this can't be that complicated. But this time it needed to be with tuples.

Comment: Doesn't really "Combine Slice and Index", though, and would be inconvenient with large slices. Although large tuples and this large tuple slices are admittedly probably uncommon.

Comment: @KellyBundy it acutally does. I added how to do it.

Comment: The added one does, yes. Though I'd use `b = *range(2), 3`

Comment: @KellyBundy, great idea, I added it. You have to be careful though because this will give you a `tuple` which needs to be converted to a `list` to work for indexing purposes. Else it will be identified as multi dimensional indexing.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm not using numpy much, and for once, I didn't test. In that case, `[*range(2), 3]` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you can implement an indexer and use simple syntax to get the results:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence

class SequenceIndexer:

    def __init__(self, seq: Sequence):
        self.seq = seq

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if not isinstance(item, tuple):
            return self.seq[item]

        result = []
        for i in item:
            if isinstance(i, slice):
                result.extend(self.seq[i])
            else:
                result.append(self.seq[i])

        return result


a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
indexer = SequenceIndexer(a)
print(indexer[:2, 3])            # [1, 2, 4]
print(indexer[:3, 2, 4, -3:])    # [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use unpacking but dont name the parameters you dont need you can name them as underscore (_).

`one, two, _, four, _ = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

now you have your numbers.
this is one simple way.

`b = (one, two, four)`

or you can use numpy as well.